# C# using an IF statement to check if user enters correct DateTime date which is a birthday

Tags: c#

I have a Customer class, and I used the DatTime constructor and set the Date of Birth(bday).
In the main program I have an instance of the Customer class and would like to check if user enters the same birthday that was was originally set in the class.

```
 public class Customer
{
    public string Name;
    public int PinNumber = 2321;
    public double AccBalance = 250.00;

    public DateTime bday = new DateTime(1875,05,22);
```

main program

```
person1.bday = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
      
        if (person1.bday == 1875,05,22)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
```

I get an error saying ''==' operator cannot be be applied to operands of type 'DateTime' and 'int'

Comment: Did you just forget the `new DateTime()` part when trying to create your `DateTime` object, exactly like you did in the previous code snippet?

Comment: Use PascalCase for public properties, please..

Comment: How do you expect `1875,04,22` to evaluate? It's neither an object nor a string.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I blame VB, cough cough #01/01/1970# cough, setting all these unrealistic expectations of "sling any old carp in and the computer will work it out" :)

Answer (score 1):

When doing a comparison the data type on both end should be same
You should create a date object when doing comparison in your code

```
       if (person1.bday == new DateTime(1875,5,22))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the three integers in your if statement to a DateTime:

```
if (person1.bday.equals(new DateTime(1875,05,22)) {
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```